# Payment from service to bank account

Tags: payment-gateway

Is it possible to make a payment from some service to the bank account in Europe or somewhere? (I would like to find two way operational service - so I can pay from user bank account (credit card credentials) to the service AND!! from service to the bank account.

So far I found out that Stripe can only send money to US bank accounts,
and PayPal can only send money to another PayPal account, not the bank account...

Answer (score 2):

There are several payment gateways that offer international payouts directly to bank accounts. All of the payment gateways will have some restrictions on the payments - they will want to know who is receiving the payment and run some "know your customer" checks.

One payment gateway that does this is BlueSnap, who can pay out to bank accounts worldwide (and of course, get payments in from anywhere). You can use the marketplace feature to set up bank account/recipients via an API. Then you can assign a percent of any incoming payment to go out to one of these bank accounts (you can set it on the transaction).

https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Basics/docs/marketplace-overview

Other payment gateways may offer similar things, each with their own take on setting up the bank accounts and which details are required to verify the recipient is legal. However, all payment gateways will require these details to meet with payment card industry (PCI) requirements.